# Rails 4 - MissingTemplate/Missing Partial Error, Only in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, partial-views, content-type

We just secured our application with an SSL certificate. Moving to HTTPS is proved more complex than we thought and we're currently sorting through a few of the resulting bugs.

We have an AJAX call in CoffeeScript, where rails responds by rendering the html of a partial. This is working perfectly in development.

CoffeeScript:

```
coffee_method: (pos, uid) =>

  $.ajax '/contoller/test/',
    type: 'POST'
    data:
      pos: pos
      uid: uid
    success: (data) ->
      $('#result-div').html(data) #Populates side menu with _next_destination_menu content
    error: ->
      alert 'How embarassing! Something went wrong - please try your search again. '
```

Controller:

```
def test
  ... #do some stuff

  puts "format requested: #{request.format}"
  puts "format url_encodeded: #{request.format.url_encoded_form?}"

  render partial: 'trips/_test' #app/views/trips/_test.html.erb

end
```

However, in production, we get the following error:
`ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing partial trips/_test with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:url_encoded_form], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.`

After some digging, I figured out the request in production was a different format. Using those `puts` lines in the controller to debug, here are the results:

Production:

```
format requested: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
format url_encodeded: true
```

Development:

```
format requested: */*
format url_encodeded: false
```

What is the best way to handle this issue. Do I:

- Change the content type of every AJAX call in the CoffeeScript?
- Add a `respond_to...format.url_encoded_form {render partial: trips/test}` to the controller?

The latter seems like I would be duplicating code, because I want to render the same partial, regardless of the format the request comes in. I tried `format.all {...}` but encountered the same issue. Any best practices are appreciated!

**Update:**

Specifying the response type directly gives me the same missing template error:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html  {render partial: 'trips/test'}
  format.json  {render partial: 'trips/test' }
  format.url_encoded_form {render partial: 'trips/test'}
end
```

**Update 2:**

The Request headers for both localhost and production are the same, the content type is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, even though `format.url_encoded_form?` returns false.

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:37
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Are you using a proxy (like nginx?) that could be altering the request?

Comment: @NickTomlin - I don't believe we're using a proxy, but we're using AWS CloudFront for a web distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try passing in the format, locale, and handlers exactly as requested:

```
render(
     partial: 'trips/test',
     formats: [:html, :js, :json, :url_encoded_form],
     locale: [:en],
     handlers: [:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder])
```